# Nginx 2 locations to serve files differently configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I hope this finds you well. My tech stack is Nginx, React, PHP and MySQL. I want to have all requests on the browser point to index.html so react-router doesn't give me a blank page, so I don't need to use hashing in the URLS (e.g. /#/test, /#/greeting). Adding to this, I also want to be able to call simple php files located in /controllers through ajax calls. Is this possible given my setup?

**example.com.conf**

```
Location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html
    root /var/www/html/example/dist;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html
}

Location /controllers {
    root /example;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

**Folder Structure**

```
-var
----html
-------example
----------dist
----------controllers
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I am not sure about you Folder structure, because you have in your config `/var/www/html...` and in the Folder structure block `/var/html...`, so I assumed you have `/var/www/html...`.

The below nginx config file should work, but I don't have tested it. Maybe you need to adjust some values a little bit (e.g. root of the php location block).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    root /var/www/html/example/dist;

    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
    }

    location /controllers {
        root /var/www/html/example;
    }

    location ~* \.(php|phtml)$ {
        root /var/www/html/example;
        fastcgi_index           index.php;
        fastcgi_pass            unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        include                 /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout    30000;
    }
}
```

---

**Additional**:

It should be one primary root folder and then for specific use cases root definitions within a location block: [Nginx Wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)